# Ask for capturing devices each time getusermedia is called : WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a simple app for webrtc calls but I need to ask for the devices each time i make a new call as it happens in Firefox, but in Chrome it asks only once. Can anyone please suggest me how can I make chrome forget the default setting for the devices and make it again ask for choosing them.

I want the popup from browser to select the devices each time I make a call.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Not sure that you can, although I think I saw a dupe some times ago. What you could do however is creating this menu yourself. You can get the list of all available devices thanks to the [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) method.

Comment: Yes, i thought of that but for that, i need to write it in my application. I want the browser to ask me again as it was asking for the very first time.

Comment: Ah only for **your** own browser ? Then you just have to click on the small `i` icon or lock icon for https sites at the left of the address bar, and set *Camera* and *Microphone*  to *always ask*

Comment: No its an application for the customer they want the popup each time call is made from the browser.

Comment: Then either you implement it yourself (webrtc group has an already made example on their github that I'll have to find back), either you tell your customer to set their browser to always ask for it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "select the devices" since Chrome's permission prompt is a yes/no permission prompt, always giving you the default device. It's not a device chooser as well like in Firefox. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?